# How to create AWS Security Group that restricts inbound traffic only from Kubernetes on Google Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds, google-kubernetes-engine

AWS RDS Security Groups are great for restricting to specific IP addresses.

My Google Cloud deployment is an Ingress at a static IP. The Ingress points to one or several nodes. Those nodes have non-static IP addresses.

**How do I restrict AWS RDS to only those nodes?**

(Restricting to the Ingress IP would not, and does not, work.)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: xxxxx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: xxxxx-ip
  labels:
    app: xxxxx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: xxxxx
              servicePort: 3000
```

Answer (score 3):

Google Kubernetes nodes are ephemeral and if enabled autoscale. This means that you cannot rely upon the IP address of a node or collection of nodes. At this time, Google does not support assigning a static pool of addresses to a GKE cluster.

There is an opensource project KubeIP which can help you solve this. I have not used this project on GKE, do your own research on viability for your project.

[KubeIP](https://github.com/doitintl/kubeip)

Don't forget that you will be charged for allocated static IP addresses that are not assigned to a Google service (Load Balancer, Compute Engine, etc).

Comment: Thank you. Since posting, I have found out that Google Cloud NAT is precisely what this is supposed to solve. What Cloud NAT does is route all outbound traffic from the cluster through a single outbound IP address, which can be made static. This static outbound IP address can be added to external whitelists.

Comment: Using Google Cloud NAT with GKE appears to make using `kubectl logs` and `kubectl exec` unavailable: "No SSH tunnels currently open. Were the targets able to accept an ssh-key." It is unclear as of right now how I am supposed to resolve this issue.

Comment: Cloud NAT is used for instances that do NOT have public IP addresses. Your new issues are caused by breaking VPC routing. To use Cloud NAT means that your cluster is also a "Private Cluster" which means the nodes do not have public IP addresses.